# Facebook not honoring og:description

Tags: facebook

I am noticing that the Facebook debugger/linter tool correctly parses my og:description but when I share the link, the output takes the scrapped content from the body text which has a class and ID of 'content'. If I delete all body text then it will output the og:description correctly when sharing.

Basically, it seems like Facebook has a preference for using body content over og:description.

Can anyone confirm this or maybe tell me why this is happening?

I would like to have Facebook share the og:description regardless of body content.

Update: Here is a paste of the HTML for now => http://paste.ubuntu.com/5989551/

Comment: We will need the URL in question to confirm.

Comment: This is an internal development URL at the moment and I can't post it here because NBCUniversal has policies against this right now. :/  Maybe I can try to recreate the issue on a vanilla html site.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Please at least say why.

Comment: Here is a paste of the HTML for now => http://paste.ubuntu.com/5989551/

Comment: Try recreating the issue until then, it's difficult to deduce the problem without running the URL through the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this was an issue with the Drupal FB module not actually submitting what was defined as the og:description. I didn't even realize that you could override the og:tags in that sense.